# Manage migrations with truffle

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

Is there a way to manage migrations with truffle ?
I mean by migrationa change to a new version of a smartcontract.

Let's suppose this smartcontract:

```
contract SimpleStorage {
  uint storedData;

  function set(uint x) public {
    storedData = x;
  }

  function get() public view returns (uint) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
```

In order to deploy it, i run:

```
$ truffle migrate
```

At this step, everything works fine: The contract is deployed and i can interact with it.

Now, let's suppose i add a function to this contract:

```
contract SimpleStorage {
  uint storedData;

  function set(uint x) public {
    storedData = x;
  }

  function get() public view returns (uint) {
    return storedData;
  }

  function inc() public {
    storedData += 1;
  }
}
```

I run again

```
$ truffle migrate
```

A new version of my contract is deployed to a new address. The previous contract is still deployed because we cannot delete anything on a blockchain.

Is there a way for truffle to "copy" storedData variable value from the old contract deployment to the new ?

What is the goal of "truffle migrations": Is it a version system management or something else ?

Thanks